# Setting the checked attribute of radio buttons with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to post to a web form but I am having an issue with radio buttons. I pass the value to the parameters but when I make the call, the site replies telling me I have to select one choice. I think there is some javascript validation that asks for the checked attribute. Is there any form I can bypass this ? Maybe set the checked attribute and then make the curl post ?
This is the html code of the form :

```
<div class="unit"><input type="radio" tabindex="11" value="4" id="atrib_1" name="attr_frete" class="radio_bt"></div> <label for="atrib_gratis" class="radio_label">Flete 1</label> <div class="unit"><input type="radio" tabindex="11" value="5" id="atrib_2" name="attr_frete" class="radio_bt"></div> <label for="atrib_gratis" class="radio_label">Flete 2</label></div>
```

And this is the code in PHP to post:

```
$parametros_post = array('STEP'=>$value1,'qb4_cat_id' =>$value2,'title'=>$model->Titulo,'description'=>$model->Descripcion,'tag_1' =>'','tag_2' =>'','tag_3' =>'','tag_4' =>'','tag_5' =>'','tag_6' =>'','attrib_34' =>'414','dinheiro' =>'true','deposito-bancario' =>'false','cheque' =>'false','cartao-credito' =>'false','combinar' =>'false','bb_file_input' =>$foto1,'preco' =>$model->Precio,'qt_estoque' =>'1','attr_frete' =>'5');
$result = $this->PostCurl("http://www.site.com/publicar-anuncio-gratis.html?sent=true",$parametros_post);

function PostCurl($url,$parametros_post){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parametros_post);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $rerror = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($rerror != ""){
            return $rerror;
        }
        else
            return $result;

    }
```

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: <div class="unit"><input type="radio" tabindex="11" value="4" id="atrib_1" name="attr_frete" class="radio_bt"></div>
<label for="atrib_gratis" class="radio_label">Flete 1</label>
<div class="unit"><input type="radio" tabindex="11" value="5" id="atrib_2" name="attr_frete" class="radio_bt"></div>
<label for="atrib_gratis" class="radio_label">Flete 2</label>

And this is how I pass the value:

'attr_frete='.urlencode(4).

Comment: I did mean: where is your current code of "posting to a web form"? And you have to place it in the question's body, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

You think wrong. There is no Javascript interfering with your curl request. It is all server side, and when analyzing the form you want to send with curl, you probably missed some important fields that are now missing.

What does the post request look like if you use the original form? What does it look like when you use curl? If you compare these two, you should find the difference.

If there is none, you might suspect there is some checking against automated requests going on, but there is no evidence yet.

Comment: How can I see the post request to compare? Forgive my absence of knowledge but I only see that when I submit the form via curl, I get a response from the web site telling me I need to check one of the radio buttons, and the radio buttons appear both unchecked.